# Unable to create customer account on frontend

Tags: error, email-templates, ce-1.9.1.0, customer-account, fatal-error

When I try to create a customer account than I cause fatal error as:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `setMessageBody()` on a non-object in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php` on line 412.

Please advise how I can resolve this error.

Comment: Hello, Do you have a solutions for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved, I have just replaced the Template.php and Queue.php files under the app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email with Magento files and its works for me.

Comment: you shouldn't change core files